# Pie chart in ggplot not a full circle

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, pie-chart

I'm trying to produce a pie chart using `ggplot2` that shows the proportion of `TRUE` and `FALSE` in an indicator variable.

```
flag <- sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.2, .8))
```

My first attempt used:

```
gg_pie <- ggplot(data = as.data.frame(flag), aes(x = factor(1), fill = factor(flag)))
gg_pie <- gg_pie + geom_bar(width=1)
gg_pie <- gg_pie + coord_polar(theta = 'y')
gg_pie <- gg_pie + labs(x="", y="")
gg_pie <- gg_pie + scale_x_discrete(breaks=NULL) + scale_y_discrete(breaks=NULL)
gg_pie <- gg_pie + theme(panel.background = element_blank())
gg_pie
```

[image]

However, doing it this way doesn't allow me to place labels over each wedge with the percentage shown, due to the `Error in unit(tic_pos.c, "mm") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0` error. Thus I tried doing the number crunching myself and passing `ggplot()` data of length 2 instead.

```
df_pie <- as.data.frame(c(mean(flag), mean(!flag)))
names(df_pie) <- "ave_flag"
gg_pie <- ggplot(data = df_pie, aes(x = factor(1), fill = factor(ave_flag)))
gg_pie <- gg_pie + geom_bar(width=1)
gg_pie <- gg_pie + coord_polar(theta = 'y')
gg_pie <- gg_pie + labs(x="", y="")
gg_pie <- gg_pie + scale_x_discrete(breaks=NULL) + scale_y_discrete(breaks=NULL)
gg_pie <- gg_pie + theme(panel.background = element_blank())
gg_pie <- gg_pie + geom_text(aes(y = c(ave_flag[1]/2, ave_flag[1] + ave_flag[2]/2), label = ave_flag))
gg_pie
```

But this gives me the following pie chart, which has clearly been cooling on the window long enough for the local rapscallions to take a few slices.

[image]

I've tried varying any number of things within this code. I thought it might be a problem with ggplot not recognizing the factor levels as numbers, so I tried not making `ave_penalty` a factor before passing to `fill`. But that just leaves me with a monochrome circle. I've tried using `stat="identity"` instead of binning, but that just fails with an error.

Can anyone suggest a way to either (a) make the second pie accurately reflect the data or (b) place the two labels over the first pie chart, even though the data in questions does not have length 2?

Comment: Just to note that your representation of the bar in different coordinates is not the principal force in your problem. If you can get the same plot to represent what you want without the `gg_pie <- gg_pie + coord_polar(theta = 'y')` then you will be able to add that back in. Also, one gets an entertaining result with `theta = 'y'` and `gg_pie <- gg_pie + scale_x_discrete() + scale_y_discrete()`

Comment: Just don't use a pie chart

Comment: there _is_ a reason there is no `geom_pie` in ggplot2. you could try to use `waffle::waffle(table(flag))` as an alternative

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks for the alternative, I'll definitely keep it in my back pocket for future use. Hadley Wickam's "A Layered Grammar of Graphics" treats the pie chart as a pretty standard thing you'd want to do, and suggests that the reason there's no `geom_pie` in ggplot2 is because of the "deep similarities that underlie the bar
chart [and] pie chart". In my case, effective or not it's certainly still something I'd like to be able to do, as my employer has asked me to produce a pie chart.

Comment: Since you referenced @hadley, he would probably tell you himself to not use a pie chart. But it's your choice whether you want to be stylish or if you want to effectively communicate the data. When in a position to _have to_ produce many charts for security dashboards and asked to use a pie chart I made my case and never, ever made a pie chart (ever).